# TFS 2018 Release Management to IIS

Tags: iis, tfs, release-management, build-server

I am setting up a release for the first time in 2018 Release Management.  We have a website that we want deployed to IIS.

The build definition is setup and has created the artifacts.  When I setup the release definition I select the IIS Website Deployment template which gives me two tasks.

1. IIS Web App Manage
2. IIS Web App Deploy

They seem to cover similar ground, but I cannot find documentation to tell me how they are different.  Do I need both?

When I configure IIS Web App Deploy, the Website Name field is grayed out.  The link icon tells me

> This setting is linked to the 'Website name' (Parameters.WebsiteName)
>   process parameter.

So I created the process parameter in the release definition and the build definition with a different name.  However the Website Name does not update.  Is there a way to manually edit this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

**IIS Web App Manage**

This task does *provisioning*, for example creating an IIS Web Site and Application Pool. Typically this is only needed the first time deploying to a target machine, but there is no harm in running it on every deploy, since it then just skips creating already existing items.

**IIS Web App Deploy**

This task deploys your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a **Deployment Group** before using the IIS Website Deployment template. Deployment groups in VSTS/TFS make it easier to organize the servers that you want to use to host your app. A deployment group is a collection of machines with a VSTS/TFS agent on each of them. Each machine interacts with VSTS/TFS to coordinate deployment of your app.

Useful link and blog for your reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/archive/apps/aspnet/aspnet-from-vsts-to-windows-vm?view=vsts
- https://abelsquidhead.com/index.php/2017/11/28/build-and-deploy-to-multiple-iis-servers-and-sql-server-using-vsts/

If you don't want to use this template, you could also try other extensions, such as [IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp).

Answer (score 0):

Both tasks are needed.  The website name is set on the Environment level then referenced in all of the tasks within.